# How do I link my libraries in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is the error that flash gives me when I publish: Warning: No libraries were linked as Runtime Shared Libraries (RSLs) because of your publish settings: Windows Projector.

I am publishing a .swf, .exe, and a HTML. The .swf works perfectly, everything works..but the .exe and HTML don't work correctly, the buttons can't be pressed and the code doesn't function properly at all.

I have tried to merge code, but it only removes the error code and does not solve the problem. I do use TLF text, but I don't understand how or what type of text I should change it to. When I embed should I use the classic or should I use the TLF? All my movieclips, buttons, etc. should all of these be changed to Classic static or something?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Actionscript 3.0 in Flash Professional CS5

Comment: What is your flash player target? It seems there was a problem with 10.2 http://forums.adobe.com/thread/860063

Answer (score 0):

there should be publish setting to include the RSLs.  Something like 'merge into code'? maybe? I don't have latest flash ide, so I'm relying on memory.

File -> Actionscript Settings -> Library Path -> Runtime Shared Library Settings -> change to: 'merged into code'

Explained here: http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs5/rsltip/

Comment: I have explained in my question that merge the code did not work, it only removed the error

Comment: right, then yes, use Classic Text unless there's something specific you need to do which requires TLF. (for example right to left text and flowing text across multiple tfs.